# Box space always returning float values in OpenAI gym

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying to get started with reinforcement learning using OpenAI Gym. I tried to tackle the Hotter-Colder exercise (https://gym.openai.com/envs/HotterColder-v0/).

For the action space, i am trying to pass a Box space to ensure it is a continuous space. Even though i am specifying the type as int32, when i train the model via model.learn it always gets the values as float32 between 0 and 2.5.

As you can see in the code below, the action_space is specified with a Box as int32 but during the training and prediction phase, the action value is always array[float32]. Furthermore, rather than get values between 1.0 and 100.0, the values seem to be stuck only between 0.0 and 2.5. Anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
class HotterColder(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.range = 100
        self.guess_max = 100
        
        self.number = 0
        self.guess_count = 0
        self.action_space = Box(low=1,high=100,shape=(1,),dtype=np.int32)
        self.observation_space = Discrete(4)
        self.state = 0
        np.random.seed(0)
        
    def reset(self):        
        self.number = np.random.randint(low=1, high=self.range)
        self.guess_count = 0
        self.observation = 0
        return self.state
    
    def render(self):
        pass

    def step(self, action):                
        guess =int( action[0])
        
        if guess < self.number:
            self.state = 1
        elif guess > self.number:
            self.state = 3
        else:
            self.state = 2
        
        self.guess_count += 1        
        done = self.guess_count >= self.guess_max
        reward = ((min(guess, self.number) + self.range) / (max(guess, self.number) + self.range))**2        
        info = {"guess": guess, "actual": self.number, "guesses": self.guess_count, "reward": reward, "state": self.state}
                
        if done:
            if guess == self.number:                
                print("Correct guess." + str(info))
                
        return self.state, reward, done, info
```

Comment: When sampling actions from the action space of your env, I do get an integer between 1 and 100.  
`env = HotterColder()
env.action_space.sample()`  _# returned array([24], dtype=int32)_.  
The code seems to be working as expected !

Comment: That's the bizarre part. Sampling works just fine! But if you run model.learn(...) and you print out the action value in the step(....) function, it returns a float value instead of int32 and the range of float values is between 0 and 2.5

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand which model.learn(...) you are referring to. Could you please provide the code?

Comment: @Rhino Have you solved this? I'm also getting floats from `model.predict` even though the action space dtype is int.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently is a known issue with in stable baselines. Found this post on the same topic: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3107
It suggests using MultiDiscrete space instead to solve it.
In my case that would not be enough because im planning on using agents that require Box Action spaces. But it might be of use to you.